# Adobe illustrator clipping mask & opacity mask

Tags: adobe-illustrator, transparency

When I set opacity mask on image I don t now how to change only transparency on stroke and not entire selected field. I need stroke like on image
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply set the stroke on the opacity mask object to be less than 100% black. A grey value on the opacity mask will allow *some* of the masked image to show through it.